# No feasible direction increases the objective function, yet this point isn't a local maximum?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the optimization problem of maximizing $x$ subject to $x \leq 5$ and $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \geq 1$. if you examine the graph of the feasible region, you will see that all feasible directions for the feasible point $(-1, 0)$ yield a decrease in the objective. However, however small a region you examine around $(-1, 0)$, there is always a point above or below $(-1, 0)$ on the unit circle, which gives a better objective value. So is $(-1, 0)$ not a local maximum, despite no feasible direction causing an improvement in the objective function?

Has my thinking failed me somewhere? Or is it simply the case that sometimes, feasible directions can mislead you into thinking a point is optimal?

Comment: There is no *line* you can walk along that will increase the objective value locally because these lines are limited by tangent of circle which is vertical at this point.

Comment: But as you say in every *circular* neighbourhood there are values to the right of this tangent which have better x values and also are outside of the unit circle.

Comment: I see...so that would imply this case is technically not a local maximum then? Or does it depend on how we define local optima?

Comment: Yep it depends on how we define it. There is no better solution reachable by a straight line without passing forbidden region. But if we are allowed to take non-linear routes we can reach better solutions in any circular neighbourhood.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: [This search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tangential+approach%22+function+boundary) involving tangential approach for functions and [this other search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22radial+approach%22+function+continuous+boundary) involving radial approach for functions will give you a general idea of how much research exists concerning the behavior of a function at a point according to the method of approach used. Most of these search results are fairly advanced and specialized,  and so I want to emphasize the part where I said "*will give you a general idea*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the definition of *search direction*.

1. If you only consider straight lines to be search directions, then there is no line you can walk along that will increase the objective value locally because these lines are limited by tangent of circle which is vertical at this point. So there is no better solution reachable by a straight line without passing at least a piece of the forbidden circular region.
2. But if we are allowed to take non-linear routes we can reach better solutions in any circular neighborhood. For example a parabola $x=-1+t^2/4, y=t$

being very asymmetrically zoomed-in we can see this parabola search path squeezes between vertical line and the forbidden unit circle region :

[image]